# How to pass to RedirectToAction a parameter to another Action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, expert-system

When the user completes the survey and sends a query to the database, he should return the same view but each time with different results, depending on the options selected.

From the user's side: I have a favorite product, but there are thousands of products in the database and the survey is to help me find a given product, based on queries to the database using entity framework.

When the user sends data to the controller, the controller receives data in POST in ViewBag, the controller checks the selected options in the switch:

**Controller:**

```
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult IndexExpert(string Id)
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult IndexExpert(SelectModel select)
        {
            string age, modelife, money, typeproduct, colorproduct;

            colorproduct = ViewBag.colorProduct = select.colorproduct;
            typeproduct = ViewBag.typeProduct = select.typeproduct;
            modelife = ViewBag.ModeLife = select.ModeLife;
            age = ViewBag.Age = select.AgeProduct;
            money = ViewBag.Money = select.Money;

            int price = int.Parse(money);
            int old = int.Parse(age);
            List<Product> products = _context.Product.ToList();
            List<FirmProduct> firmProducts = _context.FirmProduct.ToList();
            List<ColorProduct> colorProducts = _context.ColorProduct.ToList();
            List<TypeProduct> typeProducts= _context.TypeHearAid.ToList();
            List<ModeLifeProduct> modeLifeProducts = _context.ModeLifeProduct.ToList();
            List<AgeProduct> ageProduct = _context.AgeProduct.ToList();


            switch (colorProducts)
            {
                case "red":
                    switch (typeProducts)
                    {
                        case "toy":
                            switch (modelife)
                            {
                                case "calm":
                                    switch (old)
                                    {
                                        case int m when (m >= 0 && m <= 25):
                                            switch (price)
                                            {
                                                case int n when (n <= 3500):
                                                    {
                                                        var query = (from s in products
                                                                     join hl in colorProducts on s.IdColorProduct equals hl.IdColorProduct into table0
                                                                     from hl in table0.ToList()
                                                                     join fh in firmProducts on s.IdNameFirm equals fh.IdNameFirm into table1
                                                                     from fh in table1.ToList()
                                                                     join th in typeProducts on s.IdTypeProducts equals th.IdTypeProducts into table2
                                                                     from th in table2.ToList()
                                                                     join ml in modeLifeProducts on s.IdModeLife equals ml.IdModeLife into table3
                                                                     from ml in table3.ToList()
                                                                     join ah in ageProduct on s.IdAgeCat equals ah.IdAgeCat into table4
                                                                     from ah in table4.ToList()
                                                                     where (hl.ColorProduct == "red" && th.TypeProduct == "toy" && ml.CatModeLife == "calm" && ah.CatAge == "junior" && s.Price <= 3500)
                                                                     select new ViewModel
                                                                     {
                                                                         Product = s,
                                                                         FirmProduct = fh,
                                                                         AgeProduct = ah,
                                                                         ColorProduct = hl,
                                                                         ModeLifeProduct = ml,
                                                                         TypeProduct = th
                                                                     });

                                                        return RedirectToAction(nameof(ExpertResult(), query);
                                                    }
                                              .
                                       ...
                        ....
             .....
.....(x30 SWITCH case)
}

.
.
.

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult ExpertResult()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

**View**:

```
@model IEnumerable<ProductSystem.Areas.ProductSystem.Products.ViewModels.ViewModel>
@{
    Layout = ...;
}

<h1>Products</h1>
<div>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Model</th>
                <th>Producent</th>
                <th>Model</th>
                <th>Typ product</th>
                <th>Category age</th>
                <th>Color</th>
                <th>Mode life</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirmProduct.NameFirm)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Product.Model)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TypeProduct.TypeProduct)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AgeProduct.CatAge)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ColorProduct.Color)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ModeLifeProduct.CatModeLife)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Product.Price)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.
>   AspNetCore.Areas_EarSystem_HearAids_Views_SystemExpert_ExpertResult.ExecuteAsync()
>   in ExpertResult.cshtml
>   +
>               @foreach (var item in Model)

As I can pass these query to one view, the query is variable and the view is constant, so the view structure is the same, but other results are returned.

I could theoretically only use returning views (over 30 views) for each other option, but I think it will be too bothersome, and it's better to use one universal view with relevant results.

I tried for one view with one query with one case of selected options, then the query is inside the "ExpertResult" action which I return to View (query) and data display works, but I do not want to create each of the individual views for a given query to the database.

Have any ideas ?

Comment: So what's the actual problem?

Comment: @ChrisPratt thank you for your answer, I forgot wrote my error, I edited this post.

Comment: Based on the exception, `Model` appears to be null. Are you returning something like `View(query)` or just `View()`? If the latter, that's your problem. You need to send something to the view as the `Model`.

Comment: Just how do I forward to View?....

Comment: By passing it to the `View()` call, as I said, i.e. `return View(myModel);`.

Comment: @ChrisPratt thank you ! I remove RedirectToAction, and I call View(nameView, query).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed:

```
 return RedirectToAction (nameof (ExpertResult (), query);
```

I replaced:

```
return View ("ExpertResult", query);
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I have to use RedirectToAction rather than View, I just create TempData and retrieve it in the next method.

```
public IActionResult IndexExpert(SelectModel select)
{
    ....
    TempData["Query"] = query;
    return RedirectToAction("ExpertResult");

}


    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult ExpertResult()
    {
        var query = TempData["Query"] as ______;
        return View();
    }
```

where it says as _____; you would put the variable type. So if you have an class called "Query" or "DatabaseResponse" or "User" you could put

```
var query = TempData["Query"] as DatabaseResponse;
```

If it's just a normal data type you can also do this:

```
string query = TempData["Query"] as string;
string query = TempData["Query"].toString();
```

EDIT: Sometimes using RedirectToAction is better than using return View(). I've come across this a few times. If you just want to use return View() (which won't change your url, but will change what the user sees), then just

```
return View("ExpertResult", query);
```

Comment: I understand, imagine that I had to sit on it for a few hours to realize that only one line of code is needed to change. Ah, this programming: P

Comment: @DominikN We've all been there!